# F# Generics and Casting

Tags: generics, f#, casting

after reading all the questions suggested as related, I couldn't find an answer to my question. Writing to you in the hope that you will answer soon and will judge leniently my lack of knowledge in this area.

I have a type to embody a function definition:

```
type FunctionDefinition<'a>(exec:int->(Data.Reader->'a)) =
    member x.Exec = exec
    member x.ReturnType = typeof<'a>
```

As you can see here, `exec` is supposed to be a function that takes one `int` argument and returns another function that takes one `Data.Reader` argument and returns a value of type `'a` (such an exhausting phrase!). The definition of `Data.Reader` is irrelevant here.

Also, I have a dictionary to keep `string->FunctionDefinition` pairs as follows:

```
let FUNCTIONS = new Generic.Dictionary<string, FunctionDefinition<obj>>()
```

`FunctionDefinition` instances in `FUNCTIONS` are going to hold functions of several types and this is why it is `FunctionDefinition<obj>` (I believe this the root of the evil, but I cannot avoid this, so I'm here).

Then I have some functions to be wrapped in `FunctionDefinition` and put into `FUNCTIONS`:

```
/// Function definitions
let unchanged (id:int) = 
    let mutable last = null
    fun (reader:Data.Reader) -> 
        if last = null then
            false
        else
            let cur = reader.GetValue(id)
            let ret = last.Equals(cur)
            last <- cur
            ret

let changed (id:int) = 
    let un = unchanged id
    fun(reader:Data.Reader) ->
        not (un reader)

let dummyfortesting (id:int) = 
    fun(x) -> "yam-yam"
```

I thought that I could add those function to my dictionary, but... Nothing of the sort! The following code:

```
FUNCTIONS.Add("unchanged", new FunctionDefinition<bool>(unchanged))
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
FUNCTIONS.Add("changed", new FunctionDefinition<bool>(changed))
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
FUNCTIONS.Add("dummy", new FunctionDefinition<string>(dummyfortesting))
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

gives unambiguous error messages:

```
// The type 'obj' does not match the type 'bool'
// The type 'obj' does not match the type 'bool'
// The type 'obj' does not match the type 'string'
```

whereas the following is true:

```
typeof<bool>.isSubclassOf(typeof<obj>) // -> true
```

It is unfair, isn't it?

---

### The Question is

How to instantiate `FUNCTIONS` dictionary to hold several `FunctionDefinition<bool>`, `FunctionDefinition<string>` instances?

or is there a solution other than keeping a generic `FunctionDefinition` type for functions that return different types?

---

One solution is to pass the desired type as an argument to the constructor of `FunctionDefinition` as follows:

```
type FunctionDefinition(typ:System.Type, exec:int->(Data.Reader->???)) =
    member x.Exec = exec
    member x.ReturnType = typ
```

But here it is unclear how to declare `exec`.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you SO much.

Sincerely yours,

Kh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary you're creating needs to hold values of the same type. If you create two `FunctionDefinition<'T>` values with different type argument, they will be different types, so they cannot be combined in a single dictionary.

**One way to solve this** is to define a non-generic interface and create a dictionary that stores values of this interface (which will be implemented by all generic `FunctionDefinition<'T>` objects)

```
type IFunctionDefinition =
  abstract ReturnType : System.Type
  abstract Exec : int -> (Reader -> obj)

let dict = new Dictionary<string, IFunctionDefinition>()
```

The `Exec` function has to return `obj`, because there is no way to recover the type information after storing the function in a (homogeneous) dictionray. Your concrete type can then implement the interface:

```
type FunctionDefinition<'a>(exec:int->(Reader->'a)) = 
  member x.Exec = exec
  interface IFunctionDefinition with
    member x.ReturnType = typeof<'a>
    member x.Exec n = fun rdr -> box (exec n rdr)
```

Now you can add created function definitions to the dictionary, because they implement the common interface:

```
let foo = FunctionDefinition<int>(fun _ _ -> 42)
dict.Add("foo", foo)
```

**Another approach** would be to make the type definition non-generic. You'll need to do some dynamic type tests when using the functions from the dictionary to figure out what value they return. You can make this explicit by using a discriminated union as the return type:

```
type ResultType =
  | String of string
  | Bool of bool
  // etc. for all supported return types
```

Comment: Thanks. The first solution (before your edit) works for me. `Exec` doesn't need to be in the interface, since I downcast `IFunctionDefinition` before using it. Great, thanks once more.